# Printing QWidget (render) outside of GUI thread

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qthread

I'm trying to [render](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qwidget.html#render) a `QWidget` on a `QPrinter` device without GUI blocking :

My print method looks like this :

```
void MyClass::print() {
    QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer->setPageSize(QPrinter::A5);
    printer->setPageOrientation(QPageLayout::Portrait);
    printer->setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
    QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog(printer);

    if (dialog->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        MyWidget *_widget = new MyWidget( /* args */);

        QPainter *painter = new QPainter;
        painter->begin(printer);
        double xscale = printer->pageRect().width() / double(_widget ->width());
        double yscale = printer->pageRect().height() / double(_widget ->height());
        double scale = qMin(xscale, yscale);
        _widget ->setMinimumWidth((printer->pageRect().width() / scale));
        _widget ->setMinimumHeight(printer->pageRect().height() / scale);
        painter->translate(printer->paperRect().x() + printer->pageRect().width() / 2, printer->paperRect().y() + printer->pageRect().height() / 2);
        painter->scale(scale, scale);
        painter->translate(-_widget ->width() / 2, -_widget ->height() / 2);
        _widget ->render(painter);
        painter->end();
    }
    emit done();
}
```

With this function i have about 1-2 sec block state so i want to use `QThread` for this issue But Qt [Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy) says :

> Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and
>   all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the
>   main thread. As noted earlier, QCoreApplication::exec() must also be
>   called from that thread.

And also :

> In practice, the impossibility of using GUI classes in other threads
>   than the main thread can easily be worked around by putting
>   time-consuming operations in a separate worker thread and displaying
>   the results on screen in the main thread when the worker thread is
>   finished

I've modified [Mandelbrot Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qtcore-threads-mandelbrot-example.html) but there is nothing to show on screen in my case. my Widget should be rendered (time-consuming operation) and sent to printer that's all.

So do you have anything in mind for my situation ?

Comment: 1) Where does it block exactly? 2) You can't touch a QWidget from a non-GUI thread, ever.

Comment: @peppe.1.From the point where we hit QPrintDialog print button until it's sent to the printer.on a network printer it take about 1 sec and also MyWidget isn't that complex

Comment: One option is to modify the `_widget` so that it doesn't draw directly but into a `QImage` and then displays that image. You can then retrieve that image from that slot` and send a copy to a thread that then prints the image.
Another option is to move move the widget's drawing code into a class that takes a `QPainter`, then the printing thread can instantiate a new object of that class and use it just like the widget would.

Comment: Even better: paint into a `QPicture`, so it's vector-based, not raster. Then print the `QPicture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the widget's `paintEvent` doesn't do much computation, then it'll be very fast to render the widget to a `QPicture`. A `QPicture` is just a record of all painter calls. You can then replay them on a printer in a concurrent job.

Alternatively, you can ensure that the widget is not used from the main thread (by staying invisible and not having a parent), and then it's ok to call `render` from any thread.

Comment: So sorry for too late reply. here is your suggestion based on `QPicture` : http://pastebin.com/xGrj4Ykd but the print result is small & cluttered :( so as creating `QPrinter` object is main issue and is blocking my GUI is there other workaround ?

Comment: You have full control over the scaling of the result. Scale it the way you wish :)